# How to paint one image over another

Tags: java, image, swing, paint, bufferedimage

I am trying to paint one image over the other by overriding the paint component.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
class imgframe{
JFrame f;
imgframe(){
    f= new JFrame("Image Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
    imgpanel p= new imgpanel();
    f.getContentPane().add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
class imgpanel extends JPanel{
BufferedImage image,backg;
imgpanel(){
    try {
              image = ImageIO.read(new File("theimage.png"));
              backg = ImageIO.read(new File("backimage.png"));
           } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("No image found");
   }
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));
}
 @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(backg,0,0,null);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
}
class imgrun{
public static void main(String args[]){
    imgframe imf= new imgframe();
}
}
```

My first image called the image is in PNG format and has transparency in some areas.
the second image called backimage is a full black image.

My output has the transparent areas white instead of black.
So is the statement `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);`

drawing one image over another without the transparency?`

Comment: That should work as you intend (other than that you should be running the swing code in the EDT). I have seen some issues with old java runtimes with indexed colorspace PNGs though.

Comment: It works well on my pc